# Missing right parenthesis in CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am trying to create a table in Oracle DB using JDBC but I am having "Missing right parenthesis" error in the following statement. I have checked on Google and also my reference books, the syntax is right.

```
stmt.executeQuery("create table Employee("+
   "Name varchar2(20),"+
   "EmpId integer(2),"+
   "EmpDesignation varchar2(20),"+
   "EmpResidence varchar2(20))");
```

Comment: have you tried running the query directly with a queryBrowser?

Comment: Ah, those Oracle error messages, they are always obscure...

Comment: @ManuelJain No i have'nt tried that yet.. But my problem is solved.

Comment: @Tejvir: if your problem is solved then accept e.g. Jens' answer.

Comment: "*I have checked it everywhere on google and also in my reference books*" - then apparently you checked the wrong books. Because the Oracle manual does not document this syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402

Answer (score 6):

You can not add a lenth for `integer`:

```
stmt.executeQuery("create table Employee(Name varchar2(20),EmpId integer ,EmpDesignation varchar2(20),EmpResidence varchar2(20))");
```

Comment: Thank you so much i have tried your suggestion and it works.. I have also tried @SumitSingh suggestion and that is also working..